# Crystal Report : How to stop opening new window on double-click of the group section?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a report (on c# winForm) with some group section(s). Now in the preview mode, when the group header is double-clicked, the group and its inner contents open up in a separate tab in the preview.

I shall like to stop this behaviour and disable the double-click effect. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent this from happening by disabling the option to drill down.

`this.crystalReportViewer1.EnableDrillDown = false;`

When double clicking the Group Header it will no longer open in a new tab.

<sub>Note: Tested using Visual Studio 2008 and Crystal Reports XI</sub>